# Random Forest important features output stability issue

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest

I'm fitting 2 *almost* identical Random Forest regression models. Both models use the same data set that have 60 features and 90 data points. The only difference is they're using **different targets** (the target column of each model is excluded from the respective features dataframes, of course). All of the cross validation settings are same of both models (number of folds, number of iterations, scoring) and the hyperparameter grids are also identical.

I'm interested in the feature importance output. However, one of the model consistently output the same top features while the other doesn't. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a *seed* or the parameter *random_state* in case you rely on sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor in order to stabilize your results.

It's quite normal to get varying feature importance since the forest is assembled randomly. Furthermore, feature importance may not be the optimal metric to evaluate actual feature importance. You could try Boruta-Algorithm/Permutation Feature Importance to get a different perspective.

Towards your actual question, maybe your regressors are better suited to predict one target variable over the other.
How do both models perform accuracy-wise on the data? This might be one possibility to explain why one model is more stable. Do feature importances remain unstable for a larger amount of trees fitted?